# Access 2010 VBA ControlSource Loop

Tags: ms-access

I have multiple fields on a form that have no values associated with them until data is entered into that field. At which point those controls have the **#Name?** value. All I'm trying to do is hide the fields using a loop as opposed to writing If statements. Here is the code working with a single If statement to hide said field/fields.

```
If Not Me.txtField.ControlSource = "#Name?" Then
   Me.txtField.ColumnHidden = True
End If
```

I can't seem to figure out how to hide multiple controls that have the #Name? flag. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Dim ctl As Control
Dim ctlError As String

ctlError = "#Name?"

 For Each ctl In Me.Controls
     If Not ctl.ItemsSelected(txtField) = ctlError Then
          ctl.ColumnHidden = True
     End If
 Next ctl
```

EDIT:
On the main form there is a subform with a cross tab query. But the problem is results on the query are populated from a combobox. So I've added fields that are not yet available in the query to the subform and end up with #Name? Attached is a screenshot to better illustrate the issue.

There is a 90% chance I'm going about this process wrong, so it's a learning process right now.

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: The .ColumnHidden property applies only to columns in a datasheet form.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to address this question if you described the specific errors that are raised by your code.  This answer assumes that the control in question is a TextBox.

"#Name?" means that a control's ControlSource refers to a field that is not in the form's RecordSource.  For example, if your query has two fields (ID and BirthDate, for example) and your form has three controls, with ControlSource of "ID", "BirthDate", and "BirthCountry", then the control whose RecordSource is "BirthCountry" will show "#Name?".  However, its Value is not "#Name?".  Rather, calling the Value property raises error 2424 (with the rather unhelpful message "The expression you entered has a field, control, or property name that Microsoft Office Access can't find").

The only way I know to check for the string "#Name?" is through the control's Text property, which is only available when the control has the focus, so that's not much help.  If you retrieve the value of the ControlSource property, you'll get "BirthCountry" (of course).  So you could check all ControlSources on your form against the fields of the form's RecordsetClone (add error handling, please):

```
For Each ctl In Controls
    If Not RecordSourceContains(ctl.ControlSource) Then
        ctl.Visible = False
    End If
Next

Function RecordSourceContains(strFieldName as String) As Boolean
    Dim fld As Field
    For Each fld In RecordsetClone.Fields
        If fld.Name = strFieldName Then
            RecordSourceContains = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

You'll probably want to do some other bookkeeping.  For example, you'd want to check for expression control sources (which begin with "=") because they won't be in the RecordSource.  You'll also either need to handle error 438 (Object doesn't support this property or method) or check each control's type to make sure it has a ControlSource property.

Comment: I don't generate any errors, I'm just trying to hide any control on the subform that the cross tab query has not yet generated. And in the event a new value shows up it no longer hides the unrelated control on the form. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Ok, but your IF statement in the original post is faulty. It says "If the ControlSource isn't '#Name?' then hide the control". The ControlSource will never be '#Name?', so the control will always be hidden. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

In design view for the form, what does the field say for Control Source?  It should be blank, meaning the form is unbound.  If it's not, then that explains #Name.

More information:  http://www.databasedev.co.uk/unbound-forms-add-data.html

Comment: It's not unbound, I set it to unbound now I'm just trying to get For Each loop to go though each control and hide that control if no value is entered into the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code I use to take care of that:

```
Sub setControl
    ''  You can use this in your loop
    Call FieldEnable(subFrm, "boxQty", booSellSet)
End Sub

''----------------

Private Sub FieldEnable(subFrm As Access.Form, strCtlName As String, _
                                booEnableMe As Boolean)
On Error GoTo errHandler
    subFrm(strCtlName).Enabled = booEnableMe
    subFrm(strCtlName).Visible = booEnableMe

errExit:
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    If Err.Number = 2164 Or Err.Number = 2165 Then ''control has the focus
        Resume Next
    Else
        DoCmd.Hourglass False
        Screen.Application.Echo True
        MsgBox "Problem with control named " & strCtlName
        Resume errExit

    End If

End Sub
```

I have to adjust many fields on the form, so this is very reusable.  I might be turning them "on" or "off"; this takes care of either.  Let me know if you have questions.

It all boils down to this method for hiding the field:

```
    Control.Enabled = False
    Control.Visible = False
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to disable a hidden field?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the field Black from table.
And then make make again the Black field in your table.